# Despite my manifest stating API8 (2.2) 5 users with 2.1 are showing on my market stats?

Tags: android, google-play

I have about 20K active downloads of my app, but somehow five 2.1 users have sneaked on to my stats.

From manifest:

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

My concern is that there are more 2.1 users trying it and unistalling it and thus messing up my active:total ratio, or worse 1 staring me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes happens when users have modified firmware. The firmware reports one version, while the kernel may differ.

Comment: While I think this is most likely to be the case, does it mean the market app is using one number for filtering but the other for reporting?

Comment: Yes and no... there are basically two scenarios. One is that your app was downloaded when the user DID have a compatible version of Android installed, then changed that version to an older one (unlikely). The other is that the firmware is modified to report as a specific phone model (like, say, the Droid X) which the market interprets as having a specific version number, based on that model. In this case, the version the Market sees is not necessarily the version in the kernel, which will be reported back via Data Collection later. (it's also possible that someone has shared the apk directly!)

Comment: Thanks for explaining some scenarios. The last one raises another question though (sorry! I'm not being awkward, just trying to understand market); So if someone installs an apk directly, the market app on that device will still report its presence back to market (if it's available on market of course).

Comment: Vending.apk (the Market app itself) will report all installed applications. Assuming the app in question is still registered in the Market, the stats are recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your app is pirated and available as direct apk download somewhere so the manifest logic might not take effect..

Comment: In that scenario would it still report back to market though?

Answer (score 1):

You should not worry about this, since there's absolutely no way to prevent it from happening. There's just as many incompatibilities in devices that are running different kernels and ROMs, even though they might be running the same Android version.

Comment: Are you also suggesting market uses one number for filtering (say the kernel), but ROM version for reporting. I'm not too concerned, but I would like to know more about how market is getting this data if anyone knows.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would imagine it is tied to `android.os.BUILD.Version.INCREMENTAL` or more likely `android.os.BUILD.Version.SDK_INT`. But this could be changed by the ROM (not the kernel.) E.g. a HTC Sense phone running 2.1 could just modify underlying source that makes it *look* like a phone running 2.2.